# Net-ssh session timeout

Tags: ruby, ssh, net-ssh

I am using `Net-ssh`to launch a remote Python script. The Ruby script seems to hang and never complete when the Python script takes a long time to execute (around 20 minutes).

I have tested the script by running it directly and it completes without any error. Also everything works fine when the script is executed in a shorter amount of time.

This is an extract of the code I am using:

```
(0..(@number_of_vms - 1)).each_with_index do |vm, i|
  threads << Thread.new do
    Net::SSH.start('ip-address-vm', user, options = ...) do |session|
      cmd = 'python python_script.py'
      output = session.exec!(cmd)
    end
  end
end
threads.each {|thr| thr.join }
```

Could this be related to some kind of timeout for the ssh session?

EDIT: I have verified that the script is completed successfully on the remote server.

Comment: Does this python script write any output to standard output or standard error? Where does that output go when you launch the script from ruby?

Comment: Yes, it does. It is assigned to `output`. Plus I have some remote log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was associated to the SSH server time out. I solved the problem by changing the settings on the server. I have added the following line:

```
ClientAliveInterval 60
```

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Based on [this](http://dan.hersam.com/2007/03/05/how-to-avoid-ssh-timeouts/) article it should be possible to make a similar modification on the client:

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`