# SSH connection fails to disconnect

Tags: ssh, docker, net-ssh

I have a long-running process (sometimes > 2 hours) that opens an SSH connection (ruby's `Net::SSH` library), runs a command, then closes the connection. This worked fine in our old VM environment. I've just ported the code to Docker images in GKE and now the SSH connections get stuck open. This seems to only happen for jobs that run for more than about 30 minutes.

I've checked on both ends, and on the remote/server end (in `/var/log/secure`) I can see that the connection established, session opened, and then session closed. With `netstat -a` I can see that the connections are no longer listed. But on the local/client end, `netstat -a` shows the connections still "ESTABLISHED". For some reason it's not getting the notice of the disconnect.

Given that this works in one environment and not another, I don't *think* the problem is in `Net::SSH` but rather in some configuration that is different or some networking that is different.

I've tried adding a keep-alive to the client-side code (in the thought that the keep-alive would trigger the client to detect when the server was no-longer connected), but that seems to make no difference:

```
  Net::SSH.start(Settings.ssh.host, Settings.ssh.user, options) do |ssh|
    ssh.send_global_request("keep-alive@openssh.com")
    response = ssh.exec!(cmd)
  end
```

Similarly, I updated `sshd` on the server to include keep-alive ([per this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34912800/201911)), but that doesn't seem to have resolved it:

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appears that setting the server configuration to keep the client connection alive resolved this. So adding this to the server-side:

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 3
```

I had reloaded the sshd server (`/etc/init.d/sshd reload`) but that didn't seem to do the trick. Restarting the server (`/etc/init.d/ssh restart`) did seem to make the difference.